# Thunderbird: Use of master password with OAuth2

Tags: thunderbird, authentication

I've been using Thunderbird for many years now and I had enabled the use of a master password to protect my account passwords.

Now all of my accounts are using OAuth2 authentication. Is the use of a master password of any use or is it redundant?

Comment: What kind of an answer are you looking for : Whether OAuth2 authentication is so good that nothing else is required? Whether one can have too many safeguards? - There are no answers to these questions, not without you defining what are the attack vectors you wish to protect yourself against. And more: How do you define attack vectors you don't know about? - Again, no answer is possible,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question revolves around the storage of passwords, in your case allegedly encrypted by Thunderbird's Master Password, on your computer in a profile directory.

This gets into a technical and complicated part of how Thunderbird stores passwords, which has changed in major ways over the last decade or so. I would first direct you to your own profile directory, which may have old cruft left over from many years ago. It may or may not have as many as three different ways to store your passwords, namely `logins.json` (as of 2018), `signons.sqlite` (older), and `signons.txt`. There were also some files ending in the solitary "`.s`" which may have preceded that. Since your profile could have been edited, corrupted, repaired, or moved indiscriminately from a previous computer, there is no way to know if any of those files exist which might have your current password on your computer. Regardless, change all of your passwords and don't use the same ones from... 2004.

Here is a link to finding your profile directory: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird
And another link that tells you what each file is supposed to store there: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Files_and_folders_in_the_profile_-_Thunderbird

Assuming that your TB profile is just storing the modern 2018 version of a password file, then your passwords are all encrypted there and are of no use to a hacker that might obtain access to logins.json.

So my understanding is that you no longer wish to type your master password on TB. **Here are the steps to accomplish this** and ensure that the master password is indeed "redundant" in your words, or "superfluous" in mine.

1. Take a look at your TB profile and look for old password files, just in case. Delete old password files (listed above) with old file dates. Obviously, do not remove any of the files with recent file dates. View the files in Notepad or a third-party raw text viewer with Word Wrap on. Your `logins.json` will list your passwords in encrypted forms, so there is no need to mess with it.
2. Go to Tools -> Options -> Security -> Saved Passwords... and Click Remove All.
3. Remove your TB Master Password. Tools -> Options -> Security -> Uncheck Use a master password.
4. Exit Thunderbird once that process is complete.
5. **Change your OAuth2 e-mail passwords with Google, et al.** (Important step. This step essentially negates any question of whether your locally-stored passwords are valid if obtained and decrypted by an attacker with access to your hard drive.)
6. Start Thunderbird.
7. Assuming you are using Oath2 for everything as you stated, all of your accounts will use that method.
8. You should now be using TB without a Master Password. Make sure all of your accounts are working.
9. I am new to this exchange, so please be kind!

And finally, there will be leftover files all over your computer with references to passwords in encrypted and not-so-encrypted forms. A **good hacker or forensic team** can obtain these files, and with enough time and money, find things about your password history. If that is news to you, then you may want to consider whole-disk encryption, Smart Cards, and other security tricks that go beyond the typing of a passcode on a keyboard.

#### Part 2 added for the Bounty

The bounty covers a bit of a larger scope, so I feel that this is an important answer to the question about OAuth2. Generally, a person needs to run Thunderbird 38 or newer for OAuth2 compatibility. Also, there is something about "newer" gmail accounts which no longer work with standard IMAP password-style logins. Since this user apparently has an "older" gmail account, the use of IMAP passwords may be an option for user ToDo. The question implies that while the user **previously used** his account for legacy email password login, he no longer desires to use this method and has chosen to use OAuth2.

Here are the relevant links:

1. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/new-thunderbird-38#w_google-oauth2
2. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-gmail
3. and the technical one from Google: https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol

You can see in that last link that `PLAIN`, `LOGIN`, `XOATH2` are permitted methods to login to a Google SMTP server. However, the use of PLAIN and LOGIN and older forms of SMTP or IMAP authentication are permitted only for those users who turn on insecure apps in their Google profile. **Google wants you to use OAuth2.** And they prefer 2-factor authentication. `LOGIN` and `PLAIN` are neither one, so older IMAP users have been grandfathered in.

**Let less secure apps use your account** is the setting. You may get there by clicking https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps or read about it by checking here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

And for those of you wondering whether everyone has to use OAuth2 in Thunderbird or any other application, the answer is no. The grandfathered old gmail accounts, especially those of us who use IMAP, are still able to use the older authentication methods for IMAP and SMTP. Brand new gmail accounts may not be able to use those older methods, as Google prefers you to use the Gmail App and other programs like Thunderbird 38 or newer with this capability.

Comment: None of this seems to answer the OP's question at all...

Comment: The OP's question left out a number of details. The answer needs to be based on a particular installed Thunderbird and Profile. So if you asked, maybe the answer is "Yes," and for me, the answer is "No." Rather than, "well, it depends" which is not an answer, the OP can answer it definitely by making his master password redundant using my steps. I can read between the lines of the OP Question and see that he wants to say, "HOW can I make it redundant if it's not already?" and I answered that.

Answer (score 2):

With standard email logins, by default Thunderbird used to store your passwords in an unencrypted database.  More recently, the database is encrypted, but with a random key (the "SDR key") that is stored in your profile and could be accessed by an attacker.  When you use a Master Password, it is used to encrypt the SDR key, protecting the password database.  If you didn't have a master password or some other means of authenticating yourself to Thunderbird, the encryption would be fairly pointless, as anyone who had access to your copy of Thunderbird would be able to decrypt it.

With OAuth2, you provide your password to Google or some other service provider, not to Thunderbird. In return, you get back an authentication token (OK, it's a bit [more complicated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code) than that) that you can use to log in to the service for a given period of time.  Instead of storing your password, Thunderbird stores your authentication token.

My assumption is that without a master password, Thunderbird would store the OAuth token the same way it stores passwords, so they could be stolen relatively easily by malware or an intruder with access to your system.  The intruder could then access your account, at least until the token expired.  I haven't been able to check whether this is true, but if you look in Thunderbird's password manager (Tools / Options / Security / Saved passwords), you will see your OAuth tokens listed there.  Hence I believe your OAuth tokens are stored in the same way as traditional passwords.

To answer the OP's question, if my assumption is true, then I would say **even if all your accounts use OAuth2, it is still useful to have a master password, to protect your OAuth credentials**.

Further reasons to use a master password would be

- to prevent casual access to Thunderbird.  I use the [StartupMaster](http://htamas.ces.hu/startupmaster/webext.html) add-on to request the master password on start-up.  It can easily be bypassed, but it stops my small children/cats deleting my emails.
- if you want to [install S/MIME certificates](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Installing_an_SMIME_certificate) for digital signatures or encryption.  To be secure, your private key needs to be stored in encrypted form, and Thunderbird needs the master password to keep this secure.

As @uruiamme points out, OAuth2 functionality first appeared in Thunderbird 38, but you can still use older authentication mechanisms with Gmail. Details of how to configure this are in the [MozillaZine knowledge base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Using_Gmail_with_Thunderbird_and_Mozilla_Suite). While Google might at some point decide to insist on OAuth2 for all access to Gmail, Thunderbird is likely to support normal passwords for the foreseeable future. There are still plenty of other email services that don't use OAuth.

Sources:

- [Master Password Encryption in FireFox and Thunderbird](https://luxsci.com/blog/master-password-encryption-in-firefox-and-thunderbird.html) - simple explanation with advice on improving security.
- [How Browsers Store Your Passwords (and Why You Shouldn't Let Them)](https://raidersec.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/how-browsers-store-your-passwords-and.html#firefox) - more complicated technical explanation, focused on Firefox, but Thunderbird works the same way.
- [Using OAuth 2.0 With Google APIs](https://objectpartners.com/2016/01/21/using-oauth-2-0-with-google-apis/) - project demonstrating that without secure storage, it is feasible for OAuth2 credentials to be stolen from one application and used in another.

Comment: -1 Wrong: The master password does not do any encryption - it's just another password. From [link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/protect-your-thunderbird-passwords-master-password): "enter a master password in order to view or use the passwords you've told Thunderbird to remember". None of this seems to answer the OP's question at all (if it's indeed answerable).

Comment: @harrymc No, the master password is used for encryption: see [how does Thunderbird encrypt passwords](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1153730), also from support.Mozilla.org.  However, it is fair to note that the master password is only used for encrypting security credentials, not all your messages.

Comment: I've added some more detail and some links to articles explaining the role the master password has in encrypting your security credentials.

Comment: Explaining how the master password works does not answer the question of : is the "master password of any use or is it redundant?". I doubt that anybody can come up with an answer to that.

Comment: The question was whether the master password was redundant in the context of moving from standard password authentication of email accounts, to OAuth2 authentication.  My answer explains why the master password is useful in the first case, and why I think it is still useful with the new authentication system.  Let's see whether the OP our the user offering the bounty find my explanation useful.